# Code errors if there are no cells to copy and paste into a new sheet using paste special

Tags: excel, vba

Code errors if there are no cells to copy and paste into a new sheet, when I would like it to display nothing, or even a message like "no results" when the filter comes up with nothing to copy.  Is this possible?

```vb
Sub DepartmentSearch()
    
' Assembly Engineer
    
    Sheets.Add.Name = ("Assembly Engineer")
    Sheets("Assembly Engineer").Activate
    
    TeamRole = "Assembly Engineer"
    MaxDate = Date

    Set rng = Worksheets("Overview").Range("Table1")  ' source table
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=TeamRole  ' filter Department
    Worksheets("Overview").Range("Table1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<" & MaxDate  ' filter date
    rng.Copy  ' copy filtered rows
    Range("A2").Select ' source table
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False  ' paste values to target table
    rng.AutoFilter ' turn off filter on source table

' Cost Accounting
    
    Sheets.Add.Name = ("Cost Accounting")
    Sheets("Cost Accounting").Activate
    TeamRole = "Cost Accounting"
    MaxDate = Date
    

    Set rng = Worksheets("Overview").Range("Table1")  ' source table
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=TeamRole  ' filter Department
    Worksheets("Overview").Range("Table1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<" & MaxDate  ' filter date
    rng.Copy  ' copy filtered rows
    Range("A2").Select ' source table
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False  ' paste values to target table
    rng.AutoFilter ' turn off filter on source table
```

Answer (score -1):

Add in a line at the start of your code like

```
On Error Goto ErrHandler
```

'  then at the end add

```
exit sub
ErrHandler:
'code to do what you want if there's an error
msgbox "No Result"
```